# Is there an include once command for cmake files?

Tags: cmake

Does anyone know a simple way to apply the "include once" pattern in CMake files?  In C/C++ it used to require a #ifdef / #endif pair in the beginning and end of the header file until #pragma once became common.  Of course, it's possible to do the same in CMake, but I thought it'd be nice if it didn't require an explicit conditional statement.

**Re-edition**: It seems that the return() command should do it.  And I'd define a macro like this:

```
macro(include_once)
  if (INCLUDED_${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE})
    return()
  endif()
  set(INCLUDED_${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE} true)
endmacro()
```

Use the macro in the beginning of your file, without any arguments.  Because it's a macro, the return is from the include command for the file, not from the macro itself.

Notice that the created variable has an odd name, but CMake seems to accept this.

Comment: What is in the CMake files you are including, and what is your setup, that you *would* require protection against multiple inclusion? Personally, I usually have the "main" CMakeLists.txt (which doesn't get "included"), and modules with helper functions (which won't complain about multiple inclusion in the first place). I don't quite see what the use case is, here.

Comment: There are various cases for which this may be necessary.  Specifically, I have a top project with subdirectories, and I want the option to make each subdir a standalone project.  So the top project and all the subdirs all include a shared definitions file.  If the definitions file prints stuff, it gets printed much more than I'd want.  And it's a processing overhead.  Etc.  So yes, I think there's good reason to ask for this.

Comment: I am not convinced about either the redundancy of printed information if subdirectories are built as standalone projects -- each project's output should be standalone-complete -- or the impact of processing overhead (which I consider negligible even for the most involved projects I'm handling with CMake, though I build from one single CMakeLists.txt (with includes) always). But I'm willing to let this rest, pointing to Tsyvarev's excellent answer both on the "how" and the "why".

Answer (score 11):

I used to use the logic that others have suggested as the solution. Then I learned that cmake has this functionality built in.

Take a look at [the `include_guard()` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_guard.html). I believe this will do what you want.

> New in version 3.10.
>
> Provides an include guard for the file currently being processed by CMake.
>
> `include_guard([DIRECTORY|GLOBAL])`
>
> Sets up an include guard for the current CMake file (see the [`CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE.html) variable documentation).
>
> CMake will end its processing of the current file at the location of the `include_guard()` command if the current file has already been processed for the applicable scope (see below). This provides functionality similar to the include guards commonly used in source headers or to the `#pragma once` directive. If the current file has been processed previously for the applicable scope, the effect is as though `return()` had been called. Do not call this command from inside a function being defined within the current file.
>
> An optional argument specifying the scope of the guard may be provided. Possible values for the option are:
>
> `DIRECTORY`
>
> The include guard applies within the current directory and below. The file will only be included once within this directory scope, but may be included again by other files outside of this directory (i.e. a parent directory or another directory not pulled in by `add_subdirectory()` or `include()` from the current file or its children).
>
> `GLOBAL`
>
> The include guard applies globally to the whole build. The current file will only be included once regardless of the scope.
>
> If no arguments given, `include_guard` has the same scope as a variable, meaning that the include guard effect is isolated by the most recent function scope or current directory if no inner function scopes exist. In this case the command behavior is the same as:
>
> ```
> if(__CURRENT_FILE_VAR__)
>   return()
> endif()
> set(__CURRENT_FILE_VAR__ TRUE)
> ```

Comment: Be advised this include_guard needs cmake >= 3.10 so you should add a minimum version of 3.10 when using this.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest guard pattern against multiple module's inclusion would be

```
if(<something-which-is-defined-in-your-module>)
    return()
endif()
```

E.g., if your CMake module defines a function `foo_func`, you may use this guard:

```
if(COMMAND foo_func)
    return()
endif()
```

---

## Do you actually need a guard?

Depended on things, defined in the module, the module may require protection agains multiple inclusion or not.

In many simple cases a guard is *not needed*: the module's code will work even when included multiple times.

But in some other cases, wrong protection may break the usage of the proptected module.

1. A module defines a **function** or a **macro**: guard is **not needed**.

   CMake allows to define the functions and macros many times.
2. A module defines a **constant** variable: guard is **not needed**.

   Like with function, CMake allows to define the variable many times.

   But if you use guard in that case, it should **check variable**, not a function:

   ```
   if(foo_var)
       return()
   endif()
   ```

   This is because functions have *global visibility*, but variables have *local visibility*. That is, if you module will be included into other subtree, the function will be already visible in that subtree, but the variable is not.
3. A module defines a **global variable** via `set(CACHE)`: guard is **needed only if** variable is defined as `set(CACHE INTERNAL)`.

   Variables defined via, e.g., `set(CACHE STRING)` or `find_library` don't require guards.
4. A module defines **global property**: guard is **needed**.

Note, that if your module uses simple (not *CACHE*) variable as global, it cannot work in multiple subtrees, so guard should be

```
    if(foo_var)
        message(SEND_ERROR "Module <...> cannot be included twice")
    endif()
```

Comment: What about the case with preventing a TARGET from being processed more than once by `add_subdirectory` (e.g. when several targets depend on it but you also want to provide a per-directory workflow for developers - not forcing them to process the top-level cmake only) . Surely it's more elegant than putting `if (NOT TARGET) add_subdir...` to each dependant's CMakeList. Are there any cons of an "include guard" for such purpose?

Comment: Not sure that I understand your case correctly... If your (common) module provides a target, then you may guard it with `if(TARGET <target>) return()` for prevent multiple inclusion of the module.